Bit manipulations
I am learning bit manipulation and have come across the following code. I'm trying to work out what it does:
long func_c(unsigned long x) {
  long val = 0;


  // sums of bits in x (done in parallel for each byte segment)
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    val += (x & 0x0101010101010101L);
    x >>= 1;
  }

  // adds the top 32 bits to the lowest 32 but why?
  val += (val >> 32);
// adds the top 16 bits to the lowest 16 but why?
  val += (val >> 16);
// adds the top 8 bits to the lowest 8 but why?
  val += (val >> 8);

  // gets the lowest byte
  return val & 0xff;
}

What are the series of right shifts trying to achieve?

thanks- yep apologies: >>= was meant to be +=.

First and most important, the code is incorrect. The three lines at the end of the function should be:
  val += (val >> 32);
  val += (val >> 16);
  val += (val >> 8);

Your comments were correct, but the code was not. With the above change, the function works correctly.
The for loop creates in val a set of 8 bytes, each one of which contains the number of '1' bits in the corresponding byte of x.
So remember, we are trying to get the number of '1' bits in the original x, and so far all we have is byte 0 of val containing the number of '1' bits in byte 0 of x, byte 1 of val is the number of '1' bits in byte 1 of x, etc. So we want to add together the 8 bytes of val.
The code gets some additional parallelism by adding the upper 4 bytes of val to the lower 4 bytes of val. Remember that each byte has a maximum value of 8, so when you add these two 32-bit values together, each byte adds to the corresponding other byte without overflow. So the 32-bit result now has partial sums of the bytes of the original val.
Then, get some more parallelism by splitting the 32-bit result into two 16-bit values and adding them together. Once again, the corresponding bytes get added together without overflow.
The final add of the two halves of the 16-bit number gives you the total number of '1' bits in the original x.

printf is your friend.
I think in the original question the comments are slightly incorrect. val >>= (val >> 32) does not add the top & bottom 32 bits but val += (val >> 32) does.
Please see the output of this code sample:
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    unsigned long x = 0xffffffffffffffff;

    long val = 0;

    // sums of bits in x (done in parallel for each byte segment)
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        val += (x & 0x0101010101010101L);
        x >>= 1;
    
        printf("Val 1: 0x%lx / 0x%lx\r\n", val, x);
    }
  
    printf("Val 2: 0x%lx\r\n", (val >> 32));
    printf("Val 3: 0x%lx\r\n", val >> 0x8080808);

    // adds the top 32 bits to the lowest 32 but why?
    val >>= (val >> 32);
  
    printf("Val 4: 0x%lx\r\n", val);
  
    // adds the top 16 bits to the lowest 16 but why?
    val >>= (val >> 16);
  
    printf("Val 5: 0x%lx\r\n", val);
  
  
    // adds the top 8 bits to the lowest 8 but why?
    val >>= (val >> 8);
  
    printf("Val 6: 0x%lx\r\n", val);

    // gets the lowest byte
    long LastVal = val & 0xff;

    printf("LastVal: %ld", LastVal);

    return 0;
}

main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:27:36: warning: right shift count >= width of type [-Wshift-count-overflow]
   27 |     printf("Val 3: 0x%lx\r\n", val >> 0x8080808);
      |                                    ^~
Val 1: 0x101010101010101 / 0x7fffffffffffffff
Val 1: 0x202020202020202 / 0x3fffffffffffffff
Val 1: 0x303030303030303 / 0x1fffffffffffffff
Val 1: 0x404040404040404 / 0xfffffffffffffff
Val 1: 0x505050505050505 / 0x7ffffffffffffff
Val 1: 0x606060606060606 / 0x3ffffffffffffff
Val 1: 0x707070707070707 / 0x1ffffffffffffff
Val 1: 0x808080808080808 / 0xffffffffffffff
Val 2: 0x8080808
Val 3: 0x8080808080808
Val 4: 0x8080808080808
Val 5: 0x80808080808
Val 6: 0x808080808
LastVal: 8

The first part of what Steve Ford said above is correct, but the second part relating to the bit shifts is mistaken, I beleive. The bit shifts top out at 64 bits, the width of long. Therefore the maximum number of bit shifts would be contained in the the bottom 2 nibbles, or 0x08 in this case. The resulting number is just the original number bit shifted by 0x08 bits on each iteration.

Yeah, I noticed the bug after hitting submit. Answer is now fixed. I like that you kept the bug in place and showed the consequences. But I'm not sure the OP understood why the additions were being done.

Suggest you work harder to HIGHLIGHT that the code shown here is known to be buggy and incorrect. It's one thing to explain where & what a bug is. It's perverse to attempt to explain results from executing buggy code...

I'm a pervert. If I could downvote my dumpster fire of an answer, I surely would. Also, I misspelled Streve's username. I'll leave this answer as is as a warning to future generations not to suck as I have sucked.

Just to make sure that I do not misunderstand, you are aware that you can [edit] or delete. You leave this answer with a bug up intentionally. But do not make very clear (e.g. using formatting, this rare case where a little noisy formatting would have my applause). And you do not rephrase so that from start your (interesting and appreciated) approach to teach via bug is obvious right form the start? I am with Fe2O3.

Yes, I appreciate everyone's feedback. I realize I can edit my answer. I just feel the original question with its fallacies presents a more interesting question, so I left it intact. I respect everyones' opinions here on SO because I learn so much from y'all. I choose to leave my flawed answer for my progeny.
